# Internal build system error. Backend exited with code 2. Unitu

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

When I create/open projects, I have this error:
*Internal build system error. Backend exited with code 2.*
I don't know what to do, I tried to reinstall Unity, but it didn't change anything.

[Here is image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Iq3I.png)

Answer (score 1):

It happens on the latest version of macOS because it dropped support for older versions of python.

Temporary workaround here: https://github.com/techyworm10/firebase-unity-sdk-editor-python-fix